# What does "¿Cómo voy?" mean?

Tags: definiciones

I'm filling out a questionnaire and there's a column that says "¿Cómo voy?". I tried looking up a semantic translation, but all I am able to find are literal ones, and they don't make much sense :/

Comment: Hello, Nathan, and welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Indeed, it doesn't make much sense, but it would really help us if you give us some context. If you tell us what other questions the form asks around that one, we may be able to infer what it is really asking you. It could be something like "What am I wearing" (_Cómo voy [vestido]_) or a typo for _Cómo soy_. It could also help if you specify the country the form was written in.

Comment: What is the questionnaire about? I could understand this is talking about, eg, a commute: how do you go to work? Or how do you reach a festival you are attending.

Comment: It could even mean “how am i doing”, meaniing, what’s tour progress regarding a project or task. Please add additional info, as advised in the other comments. Please visit [ask],[tour] and [help] to learn more about writing good questions that allow people help ypu better

Answer (score 4):

A literal translation is `How do I go?`

It's not that weird:

> -¿Cómo voy?
>
> -Puedes ir en tren.

But this sentence is more likely to mean `How am I?`, in response to  `How are you?`

> -¿Cómo vas?
>
> -¿Cómo voy? Pues no muy bien, la verdad.

Answer (score 2):

I wish you'd given us the context!  I have two guesses:

1. It's a teacher asking how s/he is doing (at teaching the class).  **How am I doing?**
2. You're being asked how you get to school/work.  **How do you get to school/work?**  On foot, by car, I take the school bus, by train, etc.

It's also possible someone made a slightly weird translation from English or some other language.